# How to fake location(latitude and longitude) in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gps, location, geolocation

I would like my webpages to think that I am almost 500 KMs away from my exact location. I am okay with my IP address being what it was and would also like to not change anything but my latitude and longitude. I am using an Intel laptop(hp bs-145tu) with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. How do I do this?

##EDIT 1:
As asked by @Carl H, What I want to do is, my location currently is lat a, long b. and i would like to change it to lat x, long y. i am okay with other things like IP address remaining same. I am trying to access some websites which work only when I am in the one of the city that this website delivers and I would like to set a location to see the food joints near to me, that that service delivers to.

Comment: Where  /how do you see the latitude/longitude ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add detail of what exactly you're trying to do.   Do you mean you want override the output of the GPS on the laptop?

Comment: This is something that you could use [gpsfake](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/gpsfake.1.html) to accomplish. It's a testing tool and will allow you to set your own location, which is then read from other applications that can use the geolocation of the device.

Comment: @CarlH, I have edited my question

Comment: Have you considered a VPN that lets you set the city?

Comment: I would have to pay a lot more than usual to use VPN to let me surf in the same country.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, you can use the following instructions to spoof your location:

- In a browser window, hit Ctrl+Shift+I
- This will open the Chrome Developer Tools window.
- Open menu (three vertical dots) - More tools
- Select Sensors and change the Geolocation dropdown to Custom location…
- Enter any latitude and longitude you want.

[image: chrome dev tools - sensors]

Alternatively, you can choose one of the preset options in the Geolocation menu, including Berlin, Mumbai, or San Francisco.

Note that for the location override to work in Chrome, you have to keep the developer tools open and stay in the same browser window. If you open a new window, it will revert back to your original location.

There's also a way to do it in Firefox : see this site : https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/change-location-chrome-firefox-spoof/